# How to punctuate overheard dialogue with a noise interrupting it?

Tags: punctuation, dialogue

How would you punctuate dialogue when it's overheard by others (who only hear it) and when there is a noise that interrupts it? (same as action?) Been flailing about with this but does this look right?

> ‘No Sweyn, I think the ring was given along with this’- there was a muffled thud -‘in payment for someone to die.’

Comment: Yes, but instead of hyphens you should be using an em dash (—) with no spaces on either side of them.

Comment: Next question has to be, how do I force my laptop into giving me an em dash rather than a hyphen. A tech question I might be better pitching to a tech site, but I thought I'd chance my arm.

Comment: Punctuation rules, such as they are, are intended for descriptive text, not dialogue. With dialogue, you try to represent what was said as best you can, ignoring traditional rules that get in your way, using whatever's available. You'll fail, of course, but that's just because writing never can capture enough of speech to do it well.

Comment: Most word processors automatically do it when you type two hyphens in a row and then whatever comes next.

Comment: @JohnLawler This is a question about how to punctuate things happening outside the dialogue.

Comment: There are no consistent rules for this.

Comment: @HotLicks It's a stylistic issue, but there is and has certainly been a convention in place since I began writing seriously fifteen years ago. [Here](https://www.touchstone-editing.com/2017/10/mini-lesson-punctuating-interrupted.html). [Here](https://theeditorsblog.net/2018/04/08/when-a-comma-isnt-enough/) [Here](https://lyssemediting.com/how-to-write-interrupted-dialogue/) [Here](https://grammargeddon.com/2014/10/31/mechanics-of-dialogue-part-3-interrupted-dialogue/) [Here](https://whitneyhemsath.wordpress.com/2020/01/15/how-to-punctuate-dialogue-commas-ellipses-em-dashes-and-more/)

Comment: @GArthurBrown, if it's outside the discourse, it isn't part of the dialog, and there are no rules. Punctuation is for speech, not sound effects.

Comment: @JohnLawler I believe you will find that punctuation is used quite extensively in prose.

Comment: @Sus In MS Word this works every time for me. Type a word with no space after it then type two hyphens, with no space between or after them.
Type another word. Them when you type another space the two hyphens will convert to an em dash

Comment: If I understand correctly... in your scenario, a noise obliterates [a word] among those overheard by someone. *"I think the ring was given along with this [locket] in payment for someone to die."*  The noise did not interrupt their dialog — they carried on — but it "interrupted" someone's eavesdropping. Is that correct? The punctuation will be tricky!

Comment: @CassLopez Yes.  Shorter: "p--p (space)" produces the em dash quickly. I use 'p' cause it's right near the hyphen. Then copy & paste as needed. Or: Ctl-Alt-MinusSignOnNumberPad (Not hyphen).

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to punctuate this is (keeping your single quote convention in place): **‘No Sweyn, I think the ring was given along with this’—there was a muffled thud—‘in payment for someone to die.’** Note these are **em dashes**, not hyphens.

This is a stylistic concern, rather than a grammatical one, but the [convention](https://editingandwriting.wordpress.com/2012/01/17/grammar-tip-tuesday-punctuating-interrupted-and-continued-speech/) is [firmly](https://www.louiseharnbyproofreader.com/blog/how-to-use-dashes-in-fiction-dashes-uk-and-us-style) established by a [majority](https://whitneyhemsath.wordpress.com/2020/01/15/how-to-punctuate-dialogue-commas-ellipses-em-dashes-and-more/) of [sites](https://grammargeddon.com/2014/10/31/mechanics-of-dialogue-part-3-interrupted-dialogue/) [giving](https://lyssemediting.com/how-to-write-interrupted-dialogue/) [editorial](https://theeditorsblog.net/2018/04/08/when-a-comma-isnt-enough/) [advice](https://www.touchstone-editing.com/2017/10/mini-lesson-punctuating-interrupted.html).

Despite what some others have commented, there certainly is a consistent rule for this and punctuation is used when writing in and outside of dialogue. Your editor will thank you for knowing how to do this.